# Closing a internal browser on Viber

Tags: html, node.js, viber

I am having a problem closing an internal browser in my Viber app.

The app requires the user location and it is getting the location by opening a Google Maps api in a browser internally

```
res.setHeader('allow','geolocation; camera; microphone');
res.sendFile('getlocation.html', {root: __dirname})
```

And when the user confirms the location, I want to automatically close the internal browser. Is that possible?

```
$.confirm({
        title: 'Please confirm your address',
        content: 'Is this your address? <br/><b>' + address + '</b>',
        buttons: {
            confirm: function () {
              values = "&address="+address
              values += "&long="+long
              values += "&lat="+lat
              $.post( "/confirmaddress", values)
                  .done(function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
                  data = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(data);
                  if(data.status === "success") {
                      $.alert({
                        title: 'Your Location is saved',
                        content: 'Please close this browser to continue <br> Thanks!',
                        })
                      }
                 });
            },
            cancel: function () {
            }
        },
        columnClass: 'medium'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what browser Viber's internal browser is running on but `window.close()` works on all of the modern browsers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

You could do this:

```
if(data.status === "success") {
    $.alert({
        title: 'Your Location is saved',
        content: 'Please close this browser to continue <br> Thanks!',
    })
    window.close()
}
```